# How to pass state from child to parent by right way in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a Parent component where is open/close logic for Child component.
Child component has open/close logic too.
But behavior of these components are incorrect, when I close  child in child I can not open it again in parent. How to rewrite it by right way,  may be with one whole useState?

````
export const Parent = () => {
  const [isChildVisible, setChildVisible] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <span
        className="link"
        onClick={() => {
          setChildVisible(!isChildVisible);
        }}
      >
        Click
      </span>
      {isChildVisible && <Child />}
    </>
  );
}; 

export const Child = (props) => {
  const [isClosePopup, setIsClosePopup] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      {!isClosePopup && (
        <StyledChild>
          <span
            onClick={() => {
              setIsClosePopup(!isClosePopup);
            }}
          >
            X
          </span>
          Content
        </StyledChild>
      )}
    </>
  );
};```
````

Comment: as abhi patil said you need to define the state in the parent component and pass it as prop to the child. To set the state you have to pass the `setState` also as a prop to the child. Another way to solve it would be possible by using something like redux but it might be overkill for your use case

Comment: I use redux in this project but don't understand how to implement it to this case.

Comment: Just go with the approach from the answer below. But if you want to solve it by using redux you just have to define the reducer for the desired value and select it in the parent component by using `useSelector(state => state.isChildVisible)` and then you can `dispatch` the new state in the child component. But this approach will by not as clean as the other one imo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

move the child states to parent and pass through the props.

````
export const Parent = () => {
  const [isChildVisible, setChildVisible] = useState(false);
  const [isClosePopup, setIsClosePopup] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <span
        className="link"
        onClick={() => {
          setChildVisible(!isChildVisible);
        }}
      >
        Click
      </span>
      {
           isChildVisible && <Child isClosePopup={isClosePopup} 
           setIsClosePopup={setIsClosePopup}/>
}
    </>
  );
}; 

export const Child = (props) => {
  const {isClosePopup,setIsClosePopup} =props
  return (
    <>
      {!isClosePopup && (
        <StyledChild>
          <span
            onClick={() => {
              setIsClosePopup(!isClosePopup);
            }}
          >
            X
          </span>
          Content
        </StyledChild>
      )}
    </>
  );
};```
````

Comment: Great thanks! It works good now! Please edit in your answer 16th string, there are two isClosePopup={isClosePopup} instead of setIsClosePopup={setIsClosePopup}